# how to match equal values and return true or false based on result in mongo dB aggregation?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

this is simple like and dislike system.i'm trying to find if user has liked the post or not.this is what i have done so far but i'm getting false if i give ids instead of variables then it gives me true for every document.

so far i have tried this code

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "vouchers",
      localField: "voucherId",
      foreignField: "voucherObject._id",
      as: "voucher",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$voucher",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$voucher.voucherObject",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "profiles",
      localField: "userId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$user",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "likedposts",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "postId",
      as: "liked",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$liked",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$liked.userId",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      usId: "$userId",
      uId: "$liked.userId",
      equ: {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: ["$uId", "$usId"],
          },
          then: true,
          else: false,
        },
      },
    },
  },
]
```

this is response data

```
 {
        "_id": "643e4ec0eab5d70d6d3b5750",
        "userId": "6438dd1af890514dff8fde36",
        "uId": "6438dd1af890514dff8fde36",
        "eq": false
    }
```

any idea why this is happening? any help would be much apprecaited

Answer (score 0):

When you specify `$eq: ["$uId", "$usId"]`, it looks for `uId` and `usId` from previous stage output. Since these are not present in previous stage, your comparision will not give correct result.

Instead, you should use `$userId` and `$liked.userId`.

```
$eq: ["$userId", "$liked.userId"]
```